# Symfony proxy of doctrine entities in php7.1 with optional parameter

Tags: symfony, doctrine, proxies, php-7.1

I'm using Symfony 3.2 + Doctrine 2.5 on PHP 7.1.
When I'm trying to reach parent entity from child I'm getting:

> Warning: Declaration of Proxies__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\User::setBirthday(DateTime $birthday) should be compatible with AppBundle\Entity\User::setBirthday(?DateTime $birthday)

I have setBirthday method with optional argument, since field is nullable, but Symfony or Doctrine does not seem to work with it correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Having the same issue right now. I'll try to send a PR to Doctrine for this

Comment: It seems to be already fixed. Try to update the package

Comment: Jep, zendframework/zend-code 2.3 fixes it

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, doesn't seem like a right answer, but still works

I had:

```
public function setBirthday(?DateTime $birthday)
{
    $this->birthday = $birthday;
}
```

And I changed it to:

```
public function setBirthday(?DateTime $birthday = null)
{
    $this->birthday = $birthday;
}
```